# C# HTTPrequest - how to get the whole request and whole response

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I have the below small console program to consume a restAPI.
I have difficulty to see *what exactly* am I sending (the WHOLE request) and *what exactly* am I getting back as a response (the WHOLE response).
I have tried many `Console.WriteLine`s with various arguments, but seems I have not managed to have a concrete results (WHOLE request and WHOLE response).

Could you help me please? The whole code below:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace TEST_API
{
    public partial class ConsentHeaders
    {
        [JsonProperty("CL-ID")]
        public string CL_ID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("X-ID")]
        public string X_ID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("P-Token")]
        public string P_Token { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class access
    {
        [JsonProperty("aP2")]
        public string aP2 { get; set; } = "allAccounts";

        [JsonProperty("aAcc")] 
        public string aAcc { get; set; } = "allAccounts";
    }

    public partial class ConsentBody
    {
        [JsonProperty("access")]
        public access access { get; internal set; }

        [JsonProperty("combinedServiceIndicator")]
        public Boolean combinedServiceIndicator { get; set; } = false;

        [JsonProperty("frequencyPerDay")]
        public int frequencyPerDay { get; set; } = 4;

        [JsonProperty("recurringIndicator")]
        public Boolean recurringIndicator { get; set; } = false;

        [JsonProperty("validUntil")]
        public string validUntil { get; set; } = "2019-12-31";
    }


    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            ConsentHeaders cust_consent_headers = new ConsentHeaders
            {
                X_ID = "d587612Xq99",
                CL_ID = "8010aFQ9127",
                P_Token = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ",
            };

            ConsentBody cust_consent = new ConsentBody //{ };

            // You may choose to edit/update any value, otherwise defaults will be used.
                
                {
                    access = new access
                    {
                        aP2 = "allAccounts",
                        aAcc = "allAccounts"
                    },
                    combinedServiceIndicator = false,
                    frequencyPerDay = 4,
                    recurringIndicator = false,
                    validUntil = "2019-12-31"
                };
            
            System.Uri URL = new System.Uri("http://MyService:8001/some/api/do/something");

            CreateConsentAsync(URL, cust_consent_headers, cust_consent).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        static async Task CreateConsentAsync(Uri HTTPaddress, ConsentHeaders cconsentHeaders, ConsentBody cconsent)
        {
            try
            {
                client.BaseAddress = HTTPaddress;
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CL-ID", cconsentHeaders.CL_ID);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-ID", cconsentHeaders.X_ID);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("P-Token", cconsentHeaders.P_Token);

                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, client.BaseAddress);

                request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cconsent, Formatting.Indented), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    
                await client.SendAsync(request).ContinueWith(responseTask => { Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", responseTask.Result);});
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error in " + e.TargetSite + "\r\n" + e.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Note: if you spot any bugs, kindly advise me, I am knew at this. Thank you very much.

Comment: I assume you mean that you want to monitor the headers, data, etc that you are sending? I would recommend using something like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see that.

Comment: You could also try [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) which is a REST client and it does exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Thank you all, I have tried Fiddler of course, I would look on Insomnia. Great tips. I was looking to add a Console.WriteLine and see what exactly am I sending, and what exactly am I receiving. Any advice? (feel free to edit the code above)..

Comment: This is my template for the above (although, can't make it work ...):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces#using-namespaces-to-control-scope
Note: my namespaces are not nested, they are separate. Hope it helps..